# Remove checkmark in webkit select

Tags: html, css

The webkit html select element uses a checkmark to denote a selected option.  I was wondering if it is possible to remove this checkmark using CSS?

Comment: Are you talking about mobile WebKit? Because desktop WebKit has never used checkmarks to denote selected options.

Comment: I am talking about desktop webkit.  take a look at this in chrome http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option

Comment: Nope... I don't see a checkmark.

Comment: should have mentioned I am on a mac.  sorry about that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's Mac OS X that's inserting the checkmark. That's what it does to all native select boxes, system-wide; you can't change it with CSS.